# Add an admin-only comments box on a custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a comment box (like the one from woocommerce from example - the one on the right from an order view).
The idea is that only admins can comment and see these and I also was thinking of adding the last comment of a post as a column in my custom post page list(where all my custom posts are being shown).

Can I get some sort of advice/alternative on what should I start with/check? Perhaps an already made plugin that enables admin-only comments for custom posts.

Thank you!